# Integration new facebook SDK by swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, swift

Today i tried to integrate facebook SDK to my Swift app but in the quick start on facebook guide page looks a bit different than my old code.
How can i convert OBJ-C code below to swift?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                         openURL:url
                                               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                      annotation:annotation];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 43):

It's pretty much the same, except instead of using brackets, you use dots.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: This was helpful for me but It would be great if someone could whip up a quick tutorial for logging into facebook using the new sdk.  I've gotten so far as to get the button to render.

Comment: There is a very clear tutorial and example here : http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/

Comment: Note that openURL:sourceApplication:annotation is deprecated in iOS 9 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737403/fbsdkapplicationdelegate-application-openurlsourceapplicationannotation-deprec). Instead use `return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String`

Comment: return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
 line fails saying use of unresolved identifier sourceApplication and same for annotation.

Answer (score 27):

## Swift 3 with Swift FacebookSDK

#### Podfile

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

#### info.plist

*no changes from old sdk*

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb$(YOUR_FB_APP_ID)</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>$(YOUR_FB_APP_ID)</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>$(YOUR_APP_NAME)</string>
```

#### AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    ...
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppEventsLogger.activate(application)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let appId = SDKSettings.appId
    if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host ==  "authorize" { // facebook
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
    return false
}

...
```

#### LoginManager (custom login, see docs for default/button implementation)

*contains custom code but you get the point*

```
let facebookManager = LoginManager(loginBehavior: .systemAccount, defaultAudience: .everyone)
func loginWithFacebook() {
    self.facebookManager.logIn(HAAccountManager.shared.facebookPermissions, viewController: self) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .failed(let error):
            self.showAlert(forError: error as NSError)
        case .cancelled:
            print("FB login cancelled")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let deniedPermissions, let accessToken):
            if grantedPermissions.contains(Permission(name: "email")) == true {
                ApiClient.shared.facebookSignIn(authToken: accessToken.authenticationToken, completion: { (err, user) in
                    if err == nil {
                        // success
                    }
                    else {
                        self.showAlert(forError: err!)
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                self.showAlert(forError: HAError(title: String(format: String.somethingError, String.signIn), message: grantedPermissions.contains(Permission(name: "email")) == true ? String.noAccountFound : String.missingEmailForSignUp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Analytics

```
// custom ex
AppEventsLogger.log(AppEvent(name: "open_app", parameters: ["logged_in": NSNumber(value: HAAccountManager.shared.isUserLoggedIn())], valueToSum: nil))

// purchase ex
AppEventsLogger.log(
    AppEvent.purchased(
        amount: Double(revenue),
        currency: currency,
        extraParameters: [
            AppEventParameterName.contentId : orderId,
            AppEventParameterName.itemCount : order.orderItems.count.nsNumber()
        ])
)
```

Comment: it works. but seems it is different from the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/873570042741264/?platform=ios  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
             openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
          annotation:(id)annotation

Comment: yeah the check for the "fb" is to support other frameworks (braintree and branch for my app) @User9527

Answer (score 22):

This has been depricated in `iOS 10`.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
```

For `Swift 3.0`, you can use:

> **Swift 3.0**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let isHandled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[.annotation])
    return isHandled
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Someone at Facebook should have to go through their own quick start docs every month to see if they're horribly outdated

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a pretty old question here but it seams that it will never be outdated as Facebook hasn't updated their QuickStart guide for a long time.

So here is the solution for Swift 4.x.

In didFinishLaunching:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}
```

In open Url:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[.annotation])
    return handled
}
```

Comment: for new sdk(5.0.0)
did finish code : 
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
and for open URL :
        let handled = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[.annotation])

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5 with FBSDKCoreKit (5.3.0)**

Import **FBSDKCoreKit** in appdelegate

In didFinishLaunching:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}
```

In open Url:

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return handled
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 9 i use:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
{   
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String, annotation: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey"])
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 9 you should be using:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
   return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

I found the potential for the Application delegate to break in iOS 9 with the annotation: `options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]` as it will not accept nil values. You can set this to a blank string and the application should run fine with facebook after this.

Swift 2.2 docs:

> You specify optional chaining by placing a question mark (?) after the optional value on which you wish to call a property, method or subscript if the optional is non-nil. This is very similar to placing an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the unwrapping of its value. The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.0.1

```
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:    
options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation:     
options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I want to support iOS 8, I have modified the function `application(_:open:options:)` in [Whitney Foster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41388696/453428) to

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let appId = SDKSettings.appId
    if url.scheme != nil && url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(appId)") && url.host ==  "authorize" { // facebook
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

and implemented additional fallback function

```
// Fallback on earlier versions
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let fbSDKAppId = FBSDKSettings.appID(),
            url.scheme!.hasPrefix("fb\(fbSDKAppId)"),
            url.host == "authorize" { // facebook
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                                         open: url,
                                                                         sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                         annotation: annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 5 with latest FBSDK (FBSDKCoreKit 5.2.1)**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

        return handled
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Facebook gave up on Apple and has stopped updating their docs for years.

As of 2021, this is what works for me with FBSDKCoreKit 9.0.0 and Swift 5.

1. The pod to use is `FBSDKCoreKit/Core` (without Core, it will just be basics, and will be missing classes such as AppDelegate).
2. Import `FBSDKCoreKit` and setup with `ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`.