# FBSDKApplicationDelegate application openURL:sourceApplication:annotation deprecated

Tags: swift, ios9, openurl

with iOS9 application openURL:sourceApplication:annotation is deprecated

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

so now we should use;

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {}
```

FBSDKApplicationDelegate what to set for sourceApplication parameter (String)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
{
    return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String)
}
```

if you have annotation param in your SDK pass as nil

**New SDK**

```
   let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String 
   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)
```

**Update 2017/04/06**: Xcode 8.3, FBSDKCoreKit 4.20.2

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)
}
```

Comment: I use the new FB SDK so it was like this, but for the rest it is working, Thanks!

 func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String!, annotation: nil)
    }

Comment: What is FBAppCall here?

Comment: In old fbsdk , FBAppCall class is used.But if you try with new fbsdk, call 
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String!, annotation: nil)

Comment: Instead of using a quoted string as the key I would use a constant like this:`let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String`
`return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: nil)`

Comment: In iOS 9 and above, source application key is available via UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey enum.

Answer (score 5):

**The following used on facebook site till (Jan 1, 2017)**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, 
                      open: url, 
                      sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?, 
                      annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled
}
```