# How to replace - (BOOL)application: openURL: sourceApplication: annotation:(id)annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Well I tried my best to resolve this but had absoultely no luck.

I have this paragraph that use to work properly. But need to resolve the deprecate method.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    NSLog(@"%@",url.scheme);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Info" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@",[dict objectForKey: @"FacebookAppID"]] ;

    BOOL result = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation
            ];
    if (result) {
        return YES;
    }

    return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I see that it is now deprecated.

iOS (4.2 and later) Deprecated:Use application:openURL:options: instead. Which produces the following. But this is not called. What am I missing?

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options{
NSLog(@"%@",url.scheme);
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Info" ofType: @"plist"];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@",[dict objectForKey: @"FacebookAppID"]] ;

        BOOL result = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation
                ];
        if (result) {
            return YES;
        }

        return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
    }
```

Thank you in advance for reviewing and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The method "**application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:**" is deprecated from iOS9 onwards. So basically as @user2559325 suggests , this call back will not work in devices below iOS9. Please refer the following SDK interface.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

**NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_2, 9_0, "Please use application:openURL:options:")**

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773711/4160199). It's is in swift but its basically the same implementation.

In objective-c it would be something like this

```
NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:nil];
```

Comment: Where would this logic be executed? If in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions the URL is not available and I referenced this article to access the url scheme but not resolved. [link](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

Comment: it would be in the `application:openURL:options:`. The FBSDK will access the plist and use the app schemes to call this method.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try. But the main thing was I don't know how to call the 'application:openURL:options:' method.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are using is available from iOS 9.0 onwards. It will not be called in devices below iOS 9.0.

Also for it to work in iOS 9+ devices. You have to add the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** key to your Info plist

> [LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14) (Array - iOS) Specifies the URL schemes
>   you want the app to be able to use with the canOpenURL: method of the
>   UIApplication class. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with
>   the canOpenURL: method, add it as a string in this array. Read the
>   canOpenURL: method description for important information about
>   declaring supported schemes and using that method.
>
> To learn about the converse operation of registering the URL schemes
>   an app can handle, read the description of the CFBundleURLTypes key.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 9.0 and later.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution for this in Swift 3.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```