# Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIApplication' and 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'

Tags: swift, facebook, inheritance

I'm using iOS SDK from facebook website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios , but when I add `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` into App delegate I receive an error

> Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIApplication' and 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate'.

I can't use Swift SDK, because my project is on XCode 8.2.1, Swift SDK for Facebook requires 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you are using `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` by this way or something like this

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, FBSDKApplicationDelegate
```

Please take a look at [FBSDKApplicationDelegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKApplicationDelegate/) carefully.

> Discussion:
>   The methods in this class are designed to mirror those in UIApplicationDelegate, and you should **call them in the respective methods in your AppDelegate implementation**.

It isn't used that way. Don't make `AppDelegate` inheritance from `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`. Let use `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`'s methods inside `AppDelegate`'s methods

You can learn how to use `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` by following answer in this question [Integration new facebook SDK by swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277494/integration-new-facebook-sdk-by-swift)

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication!) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

For more detail and easy understanding, i create a demo project with Facebook iOS SDK [IntegrateFBSDK](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/integrate-fb-sdk). You can try it.